# What is the "damage threshold" for concentrated sunlight upon a mirror?

Tags: materials, material-science, reflective-coatings

I am trying to determine the maximum $Watts/cm^2$ of **concentrated sunlight** -not lasers or laser pulses- that polished mirrors of various kinds can handle, -Aluminum vs Silver, say.

What equations are there for determining a similar "damage threshold" for reflective surfaces bombarded with *continuous,* non-coherent, non-laser, concentrated light?

-Relevant input-variables might include(?):

- Range of wavelengths in nm (e.g., 400-2,000nm).
- Average surface reflectivity across the given range (e.g., 90%).
- Thermal conductivity of the mirror (e.g., $237W/m*K$ (for Al)).
- Thickness of the mirror (e.g., 2mm).
- Etc..

Ultimately I am looking to reflect sunlight off of one parabolic mirror onto another, and I want to better understand, theoretically, the size limits of the second mirror before any surface degradation or heat-induced deformation occurs, -or anything else I haven't thought of.....

Thank you for any input/guidance!

Comment: You need to know the characteristics of the second mirror, or you decide the input it needs to handle then choose a suitable material.

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your input.  Ideally I am looking at sustaining upwards of $20-25W/cm^2$, which seems huge.  But some aluminum mirrors can supposedly sustain $100W/cm^2$, -but this is Continuous Wave (CW) (-See here about halfway down at "Broadband Metallic Coatings": https://www.newport.com/g/optical-mirror-selection-guide ). -Perhaps due to the *incoherency* of the concentrated sunlight (in my case), it could sustain even more wattage? -Maybe, -I just don't know, hence the inquiry.